# How to deal with list of Maybe and zip operator in rxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

Trying to use `zip` operator with list of `Maybe`, but got some issues:

1) I have `Posts` with two data types say `Video`, `Image` and `Audio`.

2) Now i wanna upload these posts to the server and await once every post is uploaded (Yes, i can send array, but it's just for example)

3) To achieve that i can `zip` my list `mutableListOf<Maybe<Response>` and await for result

4) Before sending it over i have to fill my list of observables

```
posts.map {
  when(type) {
      Video -> list.add(createPost()) // Awaitng Response result

      Image -> list.add(createPost()) // Awaiting Response result

      Audio -> list.add(Maybe.empty()) // Just skip this data type
  }
}
```

So problem is:

When i do

```
Maybe.zip(list) { arg -> arg }.flatMap{ ... }
```

and my list contain `Maybe.empty()` then `.flatMap` will be never called, but i need to process others posts.

I tried to use `defaultIfEmpty(arrayOf())`, but it just returns emtpy for everything even when i have data.

So how do i can handle it?

Comment: I think that `Maybe` is a potential poor choice of Reactive type, `Maybe` suggests something or nothing, both valid. However in this case nothing is not acceptable.  Consider using `Single` - if any of these fail should it not be failure, rather than no emission? If you have control over this : `Audio -> list.add(Maybe.empty())` just return `Audio -> list.add(Maybe.just(Unit))`

Comment: @MarkKeen, it's expecting `Response` type, so i can't use `Maybe.just(Unit)`

Comment: Create an empty `Response` to return

Comment: @MarkKeen, i did like that, but i feel like it's bad idea/solution. Isn't?

Comment: yep, don't add `Audio` in the first place it seems redundant, as I said, `Maybe` is something or nothing, both valid, this is not what you want.

Comment: @MarkKeen, yeah good point. I'll try to improve it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: defaultIfEmpty() just returns default result. I think you should give a try using switchIfEmpty()?